# Как на SVG реализовать анимацию теней и z-index?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, анимация, svg-animation

Как реализовать на `SVG` подобный пример с игрой теней и изменением `z-index` элементов?

> Для полного эффекта развернуть на весь экран и кликнуть для просмотра анимации.

```js
const shadows = document.getElementsByClassName("shadows")[0];
const shadowsChildren = shadows.children;
let count = 0;
let left = false;
shadows.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let interval = setInterval(function() {
    !left ? count++ : count--;
    shadowsChildren[left ? count : count - 1].style.zIndex = left ? count : shadowsChildren.length - count;
    shadowsChildren[left ? count : count - 1].className = !left ? 'span' : '';

    if (count === shadowsChildren.length) {
      left = true;
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    if (count === 0) {
      left = false;
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: orange;
}

.shadows {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: -15px 5px 20px #303030;
  width: 80vw;
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -20px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out .2s;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 200px;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -10px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

span.span {
  text-shadow: 15px 5px 20px #303030;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="shadows">
      <span>C</span>
      <span>L</span>
      <span>I</span>
      <span>C</span>
      <span>K</span>
      <span>M</span>
      <span>E</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант `css:hover`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: orange;
}

.shadows {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: -15px 5px 20px #303030;
  width: 80vw;
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -20px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out .2s;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 200px;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -18px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.shadows:hover span {
  text-shadow: 15px 5px 20px #303030;
}

.shadows:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 8;
}

.shadows:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 7;
}

.shadows:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 6;
}

.shadows:hover span:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 5;
}

.shadows:hover span:nth-child(5) {
  z-index: 4;
}

.shadows:hover span:nth-child(6) {
  z-index: 3;
}

.shadows:hover span:nth-child(7) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.shadows:hover span:nth-child(8) {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shadows">
    <span>C</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>K</span>
    <span>M</span>
    <span>E</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Красивые, оригинальные решения, особенно с :hover

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, благодарю...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Сложная анимация перемещения

Основа этой анимации - перемещение отдельной буквы вместе с фильтрами, создающими тень.

- На первом этапе все буквы из начальных позиций собираются в середину
  слова.
- На втором этапе буквы разбегаются из середины на исходные позиции

Все перемещения букв реализуются командой изменения значения атрибута "X", задающего горизонтальную координату буквы:

```
<text  x="-1%" y="50%">C 
     <animate id="anC"  attributeName="x" begin="0s;anBackE.end+1s" values="-1%;22%" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
     <animate id="anBackC"  attributeName="x" begin="anBackM.end+0.25s" values="22%;-1%" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
    </text>
```

Чтобы не запутаться в последовательности начала и окончания разных анимаций, необходимо продумать систему присвоения имен уникальных идентификаторов анимаций.

- В данном примере команда начала анимации для каждой буквы включает
  название буквы. Например: `begin="anC"`, `begin="anL"`
- Для анимаций возврата букв на исходную позицию:

  `begin="anBackC"`, `begin="anBackL"`
- Логика последовательности выполнения анимаций реализуется при помощи
  конструкции:   `begin="anBackC.end+0.25s"` Словами это звучит так, -
  анимация возврата буквы "L" начнется после окончания анимации
  возврата буквы "C", после паузы равной `0.25s` (секунды)

*Смотреть интересней в полно-экраном режиме снипета*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

text {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 200px;
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: #FFA500;
  -webkit-filter: url(#shadowLetter);
  filter: url(#shadowLetter);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 600" style="background:#FFA500;">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadowLetter" x="-35%" y="-15%" width="200" height="200">           
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" result="inShadow" stdDeviation="8" />
      <feOffset dy="3" dx="-14"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>         
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="anText" fill-opacity="0.85" transform="translate(150 0)">
    <text x="-1%" y="50%">C 
      <animate id="anC" attributeName="x" begin="0s;anBackE.end+1s" values="-1%;22%" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
      <animate id="anBackC" attributeName="x" begin="anBackM.end+0.25s" values="22%;-1%" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
    </text>
    <text x="10%" y="50%">L
      <animate id="anL" attributeName="x" begin="anE.end+0.25s" values="10%;22%" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" />  
      <animate id="anBackL" attributeName="x" begin="anBackK.end+0.5s" values="22%;10%" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
    </text>
    <text x="18%" y="50%">I
      <animate id="anI" attributeName="x" begin="anM.end+0.25s" values="18%;22%" dur="0.25s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" />  
      <animate id="anBackI" attributeName="x" begin="anK.end+0.25s" values="22%;18%" dur="0.25s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" />
    </text> 
    <text x="22%" y="50%">C
      <animate id="anStart" attributeName="y" begin="0.2s" values="50%;25%;50%" dur="2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />   
    </text>
    <text x="33%" y="50%">K
      <animate id="anK" attributeName="x" begin="anI.end+0.25s" values="33%;22%" dur="0.25s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/> 
      <animate id="anBackK" attributeName="x" begin="anBackI.end+0.5s" values="22%;33%" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
    </text> 
    <text x="45%" y="50%">M 
      <animate id="anM" attributeName="x" begin="anL.end+0.25s" values="45%;22%" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/> 
      <animate id="anBackM" attributeName="x" begin="anBackL.end+0.25s" values="22%;45%" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
    </text>
    <text x="61.5%" y="50%">E
      <animate id="anE" attributeName="x" begin="anC.end+0.25s" values="61.5%;22%" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/> 
      <animate id="anBackE" attributeName="x" begin="anBackC.end+0.25s" values="22%;61.5%" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"/>
    </text> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Я смотрю, у вас, Alexandr_TT, фантазия разыгралась)))  Прикольно...

Comment: @Air отличный вопрос, вдохновляет всегда

Comment: Я  и забыл, что ответы на этот вопрос оставил без внимания...

Comment: Alexandr_TT, мудрецы говорят - "хочешь лучше - сделай сам"....

Answer (score 11):

### Анимация тени

Анимация достигается изменением атрибута `dx` фильтра `feOffset`

Команда на выполнение:

```
<feOffset dy="3" dx="-14">
          <animate  attributeName="dx" values="-12;20;20;-12;-12" dur="3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

text {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 200px;
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: #FFA500;
  -webkit-filter: url(#shadowLetter);
  filter: url(#shadowLetter);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 600" style="background:#FFA500;">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadowLetter" x="-35%" y="-15%" width="200" height="200">           
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" result="inShadow" stdDeviation="8"/>
      <feOffset dy="3" dx="-14">
     <!-- Анимация тени Повторяющиеся цифры в атрибуте values, создают паузы в крайних позициях  -->
     <animate
          attributeName="dx"
          values="-12;20;20;-12;-12"
          dur="3s"
          fill="freeze"
          repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
      </feOffset>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>         
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="anText" fill-opacity="0.85" transform="translate(150 0)">
    <text x="-1%" y="50%">C</text>
    <text x="10%" y="50%">L</text>
    <text x="18%" y="50%">I</text> 
    <text x="22%" y="50%">C</text> 
    <text x="33%" y="50%">K</text> 
    <text x="45%" y="50%">M</text>
    <text x="61.5%" y="50%">E</text> 
  </g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 9):

Тени выполнены с помощью фильтров смещения - `feOffset` и размытия - `feGaussianBlur`
Чтобы получить эффект наложения одной буквы на другую пришлось для каждой буквы писать отдельную команду с применением фильтра:

```
<text  x="-1%" y="50%" fill="#FFA500" filter="url(#shadowLetter)"  > C</text>
```

К сожалению приложение смотрится немного по разному в `FireFox` и в `Chrome`

*Ниже полный текст приложения*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

text {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 200px;
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: #FFA500;
  -webkit-filter: url(#shadowLetter);
  filter: url(#shadowLetter);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 600" style="background:#FFA500;">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadowLetter" x="-35%" y="-15%" width="200" height="200">           
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" result="inShadow" stdDeviation="8" />
      <feOffset dy="3" dx="-14"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>         
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g fill-opacity="0.85" transform="translate(150 0)" >
    <text  x="-1%" y="50%">C</text>   
    <text  x="10%" y="50%">L</text>
    <text  x="18%" y="50%">I</text> 
    <text  x="22%" y="50%">C</text> 
    <text  x="33%" y="50%">K</text> 
    <text  x="45%" y="50%">M</text>
    <text  x="61.5%" y="50%">E</text> 
  </g>
</svg>
```